# Redis : Sorted sets for specific SMEMBERS

Tags: redis, sortedset

im new to Redis and try to display a sorted set for specific values that are part of a sadd. Is there a way to do this in Redis?

```
SADD friends "Sarah"
SADD friends "Lisa"
SADD friends "Tim"


ZADD users 200 "Sarah"
ZADD users 133 "Lisa"
ZADD users 410 "Peter"
ZADD users 280 "Tim"
ZADD users 205 "Hans"
```

I want to display a sorted set with score only with friends.

```
1) "Tim"
2) "280"
3) "Sarah"
4) "200"
5) "Lisa"
6) "133"
```

Comment: You mean you don't want to display the scores (keys), just the names (values)?

Comment: Yes, the result should look like the example.

Comment: I don't think you can do that as `sadd`and `zadd`are different kind of sorted sets (one with scores). Take a look at [SUNION](https://redis-doc-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/sunion/) and [ZUNIONSTORE](https://redis.io/commands/zunionstore) as it returns a set resulting in the union of some specified sets. The union in this case of `friends` and `users` would be `Tim`, `Sarah` and `Lisa`with its scores.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ZINTERSTORE as it can work with regular SETs as well. Note that it will use 1 for the elements scores, but you can remove it with a weight 0:

`ZINTERSTORE aux_zset 2 friends users weights 0 1`

The result ZSET has your answer:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange aux_zset 0 -1 withscores
1) "Lisa"
2) "133"
3) "Sarah"
4) "200"
5) "Tim"
6) "280"
```

Comment: Nice one by the way! I did not know `ZINTERSTORE` could work with regular sets!